# kubernetes: service not reachable though pod healthy

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have the following `Service`

```
➢  k get svc faros-web -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: faros-web
  namespace: mynamespace
  clusterIP: 10.8.49.178
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: faros-web-primary
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Here is the pod corresponding to the `Service`'s selector:

```
faros-web-primary-5b5c4f9475-j9tn6    2/2     Running     5          16m

➢  k get pod faros-web-primary-5b5c4f9475-j9tn6 -o yaml | grep -i label -C 2

  labels:
    app: faros-web-primary
```

However from another pod in the same namespace:

```
user@faros-worker-5ddfd69c64-wnh2f:~/app$ curl http://faros-web:5000
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
user@faros-worker-5ddfd69c64-wnh2f:~/app$
user@faros-worker-5ddfd69c64-wnh2f:~/app$ curl http://faros-web
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure
```

Using `k8s 1.12` on GKE and `istio 1.1.14`

Comment: It looks like you want to test your app in K8 alongside Istio. Is it right? Or you are fine testing your app without the Istio installation too ?

Comment: Alongside istio. But the above communication path shouldn't be affected by the presence of istio right? A pure k8s Service should be exposed and reachable via its name, from within the same namespace

Comment: Looks like the Istio sidecar container resets the connection, so you need to look for the reason in Istio, not in Kubernetes per se.